# Replace multiple words on string using Map of replacements

Tags: string, scala

I have a map of replacements

`val replacements = Map( "aaa" -> "d", "bbb" -> "x", "ccc" -> "mx")`

I would like to replace all occurrences of each map key in the string with the corresponding value.

```
val str = "This aaa is very bbb and I would love to cccc"
val result = cleanString(str, replacements)
result = "This d is very x and I would love to mx"
```

I have done

```
val sb = new StringBuilder(str)
for(repl <- replacements.keySet) yield {
  sb.replaceAllLiterally(repl, replacement.get(repl))
}
```

but I would like something more functional like a `map` or `fold` where the function I apply to the string returns another string without needing a mutable variable that is modified inside the loop.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One option: use `foldLeft` on the `Map` with `str` as the initial parameter:

```
replacements.foldLeft(str)((a, b) => a.replaceAllLiterally(b._1, b._2))
// res8: String = This d is very x and I would love to mxc
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that if one of the replacement words is a sub-string of another word, it replaces that. For example if you a word like "aaaple", it will be "dple". Depends on your application, it might or might not become an issue.

Comment: `warning: method replaceAllLiterally in class StringOps is deprecated (since 2.13.2): Use s.replace as an exact replacement`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this, but it should work:

```
str.split(" ").toList.map { s => 
  if(replacements.get(s).isDefined) { 
    replacements(s) 
  } else { 
    s  
  } 
}.mkString(" ")
```

Comment: This won't work if I provide a string without spaces. The example I used was for the sole purpose of illustration and easy understanding of the question.

Comment: I see. Well how would you split words then though?

Comment: There is not splitting. This is a string replacement problem. If the provided string is a single string, it should replace the whole string if this is in the replacement map.

Comment: My "not so beautiful" solution would still work in that case though, won't it?

Comment: My solution works too but that is not the point. Your solution doesn't work if you provide a string without spaces and need to replace substrings.

Comment: @mfirry you can replace your whole `if .. else` statement with `replacements.getOrElse(s, s)`

Comment: Gosh this is embarrassing! I've used getOrElse trillions of times and forgot about it now. Thanks Cyrille.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that. Be careful about the order.

```
val str = "aaaaaa"
val relaceMap = Map("aaaaa" -> "C", "a" -> "A", "aaa" -> "B")
val pattern = relaceMap.keys.mkString("|").r
val result = pattern.replaceAllIn(str, m => relaceMap(m.matched)) // CA
```