# Scala replace multiple strings having common character at once

Tags: scala

```
val str= " This string has " , need to escape with \ .Even string has \ before"
val resultShouldbe=" This string has \" ,need to escape with \\.Even string has \\ before"

str.replace(""""""" , """\"""").replace("\\","\\\\")
```

The output of first replace is adding up to the second replace.

Kindly help.

Comment: tried the solution given here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400598/replace-multiple-words-on-string-using-map-of-replacements. But it is doing the same thing . Once the quote is replace with backslash and quote . Second replace is again adding one more backslash

Comment: That is working . Could you help me to understand this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replaceAll("([\"\\\\])" , "\\\\$1")
```

Matching regex:

- `(...)` - capture group: Capture everything that matches this pattern.
- `[...]` - character class: Match any of the given characters.
- `\"\\\\` - 2 characters: A quote mark (escaped) **or** a backslash (doubly escaped).

Replacement string:

- `\\\\$1` - 2 elements: A backslash (doubly escaped) followed by whatever was captured in the 1st capture group. (In this case there was only 1 capture group.)

**In other words**: For every quote `"` or backslash `\` character, replace it with the same character preceded by a backslash `\` character.

Comment: "followed by whatever was captured in the 1st capture group. (In this case there was only 1 "capture group.) did not get it. Will appreciate if you help.

Comment: `$1` retrieves whatever was captured in the 1st capture group. `$2` retrieves whatever was captured in the 2nd capture group, etc. This regex has only 1 pair of parens `(...)` so only 1 capture group. If there had been 2 sets of parens, `(...)..(...)` or `(..(...)..)`, then we could have referenced `$1` and/or `$2`. [More details.](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)